# Do I have to put everything in useEffect dependency array?

Tags: react-hooks

I have a react component that I have a state mode, and everytime the mode changes, I want to update my firestore database with onChangeMode. The problem is since I have onChangeMode in dependency, it continually runs the useEffect when I just want to run it once. It seems to work as intended if I take onChangeMode out of the dependency, but my linter says I have to put it in.

What is the correct way to remedy this problem?

```
    export default function ControlPanel({
      userData,
      groupData,
      items,
      onChangeMode,
    }) {
      const [mode, setMode] = useState(groupData.mode);

      const handleModeChange = (event, mode) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          switch (mode) {
            case "start":
            case "question":
              setMode(mode);
              break;
            default:
              setMode("normal");
              break;
          }
        } else {
          setMode("normal");
        }
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("RUN USE EFFECT");
        onChangeMode(mode);
      }, [mode, onChangeMode]);

      return (
        <Stack spacing={1}>
          <ModeSwitches mode={mode} onChangeMode={handleModeChange} />
        </Stack>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to follow linter suggestion (which is almost always a good thing to do), you should wrap your method into a `useCallback`.

Before the example, the explanation: if you put `onChangeMode` in the dependency array, what happen is:

1. Component is rendered, and a new instance of `onChangeMode` is defined;
2. The `useEffect` is triggered since there's a new instance of `onChangeMode`;
3. `onChangeMode` calls `setMode`, updating the state, which leads to point (1);

There it goes your infinite loop :)

Now, why the use of `useCallback` will fix this? Because `useCallback` allows to mantain the same reference to a method throughout different render: in your case, the infinite loop will stop at point (2).
So, you need to write as follow:

```
const handleModeChange = useCallback((event, mode) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    switch (mode) {
      case "start":
      case "question":
        setMode(mode);
        break;
      default:
        setMode("normal");
        break;
    }
  } else {
    setMode("normal");
  }
}, []);
```

Note that, in this case, the dependency array is empty: this is because your method does not depend on anything outside of it (except `setMode`, but the setter state method will not change in time).

Here's a link to useCallback documentation: https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback

Comment: That does not work since handleModeChange is not part of the useEffect at all. onChangeMode is the problem. This is updating the cloud data to be in sync with the state of the component.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I confused `onChangeMode` and `handleModeChange`. Can I know how you use  `ControlPanel`? Probably somewhere you have an usage like `<ControlPanel onChangeMode={<something_here>} ... />`.
Can you add that part of the code in the question?